# How to create an Oracle datasource on Websphere traditional using the sample JDBCResourcesWithJMX code?

Tags: websphere, datasource

Does any one work websphere JDBCResourcesWithJMX and oracle datasource? I cannot set "url" parameter for oracle datasource and could not find any sample...
Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

In the sample java source, JDBCResourcesWithJMX, you should be able to set the URL attribute of the Oracle datasource by editing the soure like this:

```
// the attribute DataSource.relationResourceAdapter is required
// in addition to the attributes in the template
    AttributeList dsAttrs = new AttributeList();
    dsAttrs.add(new Attribute("name", dataSourceName));
// override some other props in the template
    dsAttrs.add(new Attribute("URL", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/sample"));
    dsAttrs.add(new Attribute("description", dataSourceName));
    dsAttrs.add(new Attribute("jndiName", "jdbc/" + dataSourceName));
```

Comment: Thanks for comment but, when I use url, i get this error.Created JDBC provider: Oracle JDBC Driver (XA)-Test_Cluster (XA) at server scope
Created authorization alias: TEST_USR
Caught exception: javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation createConfigDataByTemplate
javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation createConfigDataByTemplate
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidAttributeNameException: ADMG0005E: The attribute name URL is not valid.

Comment: I'm assuming "createXAJDBCProvider" is true?  What is the value of variable "templateName" in the method "createDataSource"?  It sounds like you're not pointing at the Oracle datasource template.  The template name  should be "Oracle JDBC Driver (XA)" by the time you start setting the attributes in "createDataSource"